# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' In flutter login and registration api

Tags: flutter, api, dart, mobile, render

I am using Node API with RENDER hosting, while I host the backend it works and when I try to connect the front end and send data I get an exception named Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' help me, please

note: password is in string and number is an int data type

```
RoundedButton(
  colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  title: 'Login',
  onPressed: () {
    AuthService().login(number, password).then((val) {
      if (val.data['success']) {
        var token = val.data['token'];
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'SUCCESS',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0);
      }
    });
    print('phone: $number && password:$password');
  },
),
```

```
class AuthService {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  login(phone, password) async {
    try {
      return await dio.post('https://parkit-odj8.onrender.com/signin',
          data: {"phone": phone, "password": password},
          options: Options(contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType));
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: e.response?.data['msg'],
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code I tried looking up everything and tried changing my data types but still no use

Comment: in which line it throws ti you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you tried to assign a `String` to a property that accepts only  an `int`, example of what you did:

```
String a = "100";
int b = a;  // throws an error
```

so you need to go from that `String` and convert it to an `int`, you can use `int.parse(/*String*/)`:

```
String a = "100";
int b = int.parse(a);  // 100
```

that's what you need to do in your case.

Note: you can do the reverse and convert an `int` to `String` with the `toString()` method:

```
int b = 100;
String a = b.toString();  // "100"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write number.toString() it will convert it from string to int.